# T-SQL: import xml with variable elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, variables, sqlxml

I have a xml File, which has a strucure like this:

```
 <Material>
     <MaterialNumber>7654321</MaterialNumber>
     <Carton>
        <IDType>qwer</IDType>
        <EncodingType>asdf</EncodingType
     </Carton>
 </Material>
```

I want to import `materialnumber` as well as `idtype` ...
how can I import when there are two different layers? I only want to switch `@Attribute`. Thank you very much!

```
SET @Attribute = 'Carton/IDType'
SELECT
a.b.value('*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Attribute")][1]','varchar(1000)') AS blub
FROM @myxml.nodes('//Material') a(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    @myxml.value('(Material/MaterialNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as MaterialNumber,
    @myxml.value('(Material/Carton/IDType/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as IDType
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22069)</kbd>**